# How to find the domain and range of a 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, domain-theory

One very simple example is $$f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$$

I know that the domain is $\Bbb{R}^2 $ but I don't know a general way to find it in any equation.

Also I don't know how to find the range of this function. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why the domain can't be $\Bbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Well i guess it can be, isnt R^2 included in C^2?

Comment: If $x, y\in\Bbb{R}$  then domain of definition of $f$ is the largest subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ where $f$ is defined. For an example, consider  $f(x, y) =\frac{y}{x}$ where $x, y\in\Bbb{R}$ then $\textrm{Dom}(f) =\Bbb{R}^2\setminus \text{ $x$- axis}$.

Comment: So if I say that domain is = R^2, is it wrong?

Comment: If $x, y$ are real variables then $\text{Dom}(f) =\Bbb{R}^2$ as $f$ is a polynomial in two variables, defined everywhere.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How about the range?

Comment: Consider parts (restrictions) of the function: what is the range of $f(x,0)=x^2$ and what is the range of $f(0,y)=-y^2$? You may know this from before, as single variable functions.

Comment: @StackTD for the 1st one i think xER and for the other one yE(-INF up to 0)?

Comment: The first one can't be $\mathbb{R}$ because $x^2 \ge 0$, but you got the second part right - now combine them for a conclusion on the range of $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @StackTD Ah yes, so I have [0 to INF) and (-INF to 0) so that makes (-INF to INF) => R.
Should i say though that range of f is R or range is R^2? Because i have my x and y going on both dimensions?

Comment: Your function is $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ so it takes values $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (domain) and maps them to values $z=f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$ (range). So the domain is a subset $\mathbb{R}^2$, the range a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ - in this case $\mathbb{R}$ itself, correct.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you. Just to make sure, the domain of f = R^2 finally? Or is it something else?